# 3 Dimentional Dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I'm trying make to a 3 Dimension Dictionary to store the data in the form of tools(material)(part)(attribute), and I have managed to create the Dictionary like this:

```
Dim Tools As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)))
```

And what I basically want to do is have some subs that manage that for me instead of dealing with that mess, and I want it to be like this like this:

```
Add_Attribute("Iron", "Pickaxe Head", "Durability", 204)
Get_Attribute("Stone", "Pickaxe Head", "Mining Speed")
```

Any answers would be greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Create a class that accept 3 parameters, concatenate the parameters with delimiter and use it as the dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

My comment was not worded properly.

Create a class with add/get attributes function that accepts 3 parameters.
Concatenate the parameters and use it as dictionary key.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oDict As Dictionary

Public Function Add_Attribute(psParam1 As String, psParam2 As String, psParam3 As String, psValue As String)
    Dim sKey As String

    sKey = BuildKey(psParam1, psParam2, psParam3)

    If oDict.Exists(sKey) Then
        oDict.Item(sKey) = psValue
    Else
        oDict.Add sKey, psValue
    End If

End Function

Public Function Get_Attribute(psParam1 As String, psParam2 As String, psParam3 As String) As String
    Dim sKey As String

    sKey = BuildKey(psParam1, psParam2, psParam3)

    If oDict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Get_Attribute = oDict.Item(sKey)
    Else
        Get_Attribute = ""
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oDict = New Dictionary
End Sub

Private Function BuildKey(psParam1 As String, psParam2 As String, psParam3 As String) As String
    BuildKey = Join(Array(psParam1, psParam2, psParam3), "#")
End Function

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set oDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Jules' answer of a custom class and concatenation of the three strings as a key will work very nicely for you and is a neat solution to your problem.

I'm posting another answer here for anyone who wants more of a dot notation style of solution. So one of the lines in your example could look something like:

```
mTools("Pickaxe Head").Attr("Durability").Material("Iron") = 204
```

I'm guessing you're deriving the values from a comboxbox or something similar, so working with strings might serve you fine. However, if you wished, you could go one stage further and create objects for the *Attributes* and *Material* parameters to achieve true dot notation (I didn't do the *Parts* parameter but you could do that one too):

```
mTools("Pickaxe Head").Durability.OnIron = 204
```

From a development point of view, the time consuming part would be to create all the parameter objects and keys, but if you are intending to manipulate the data anything more than trivially, it could make your life easier further down the track.

For your own project, are you certain that the data is genuinely 3 dimensional? Perhaps it's just the variable names that you've picked, but it seems as though you have one main object, ie the part (*Pickaxe Head*) which has some attributes (*Durability* and *Mining Speed*)  which themselves have values based on the material they're operating on (*Stone* and *Iron*). Structurally, could it look like this?:

[image]

In terms of the code for this solution, create three classes. I've called them *clsKeys*, *clsMaterials* and *clsPart*.

For your `clsKeys`, the code is simply your field names:

```
Public Durability As String
Public MiningSpeed As String
Public Iron As String
Public Stone As String
```

For `clsPart`, the code contains the object names and a means of accessing them by string:

```
Public Name As String
Public Durability As New clsMaterials
Public MiningSpeed As New clsMaterials
Private mProperties As New Collection
Public Property Get Attr(field As String) As clsMaterials
    Set Attr = mProperties(field)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    With Keys
        mProperties.Add Durability, .Durability
        mProperties.Add MiningSpeed, .MiningSpeed
    End With
End Sub
```

`clsMaterials` is similar:

```
Public OnStone As Integer
Public OnIron As Integer
Private mProperties As New Collection
Public Property Let Material(field As String, value As Variant)
    mProperties.Remove field
    mProperties.Add value, field
End Property
Public Property Get Material(field As String) As Variant
    Material = mProperties(field)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    With Keys
        mProperties.Add OnStone, .Stone
        mProperties.Add OnIron, .Iron
    End With
End Sub
```

These classes can take as many objects as you like. You'll note I've instantiated the objects in the declaration which isn't best form but I've done it in the interest of space.

Finally, in a `Module` you need 3 routines: one to create the field keys, one to populate the data and one to retrieve it.

For the keys:

```
Option Explicit
Public Keys As clsKeys
Private mTools As Collection
Sub CreateKeys()
    Set Keys = New clsKeys
    With Keys
        .Durability = "Durability"
        .MiningSpeed = "Mining Speed"
        .Iron = "Iron"
        .Stone = "Stone"
    End With
End Sub
```

For data population:

```
Sub PopulateData()
    Dim oPart As clsPart

    Set mTools = New Collection

    Set oPart = New clsPart

    With oPart

        .Name = "Pickaxe Head"

        'You could use dot notation
        .Durability.OnIron = 204
        .Durability.OnStone = 100

        'Or plain strings
        .Attr("Mining Speed").Material("Stone") = 50
        .Attr("Mining Speed").Material("Iron") = 200

        mTools.Add oPart, .Name

    End With

End Sub
```

and for data retrieval:

```
Sub RetrieveValue()
    Dim oPart As clsPart
    Dim v As Variant

    Set oPart = mTools("Pickaxe Head")

    With oPart

        'Using dot notation
        v = oPart.Durability.OnIron
        Debug.Print v

        'Using plain strings
        v = oPart.Attr("Durability").Material("Stone")
        Debug.Print v

    End With

    'Or even without assigning the oPart variable
    v = mTools("Pickaxe Head").Attr("Mining Speed").Material("Iron")
    Debug.Print v

End Sub
```